# Is there a grammar mistake in "Ball Don't Lie"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, sports

There is a novel titled 'Ball Don't Lie', and a film also based on the novel with the same name (visit: [Wikipedia synopsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_Don%27t_Lie)). Then the sentence becomes more famous in sports world after Rasheed Wallace used it in one of NBA games (watch YouTube video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkhWeEGyIdI)).

So I'm just curious, isn't there clearly a grammar mistake in this term? Shouldn't it be "Balls Don't Lie", or "Ball Doesn't Lie"?

Comment: Or is it a vocative with an imperative?: "Ball, don't lie!". Then there should be a comma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not knowing that film or novel specifically, I assume the title intentionally employs a "grammatical error" that reflects speech patterns common among the people being written about. Similar to another novel, "[Blood Done Sign My Name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_Done_Sign_My_Name)," by University of Wisconsin–Madison professor Timothy B. Tyson.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's ungrammatical in formal usage. It means "the ball doesn't lie", but the grammar makes it sound street-tough and world-wise, .

It's an Americanism, possibly AAVE derived, with the word "don't" taking on a generic "do" role, much as "ain't" takes on a generic "is" role in rural speech. Compare

- Ball ain't bouncing.
- Ball don't bounce.
- She ain't seen me.
- She don't see me
- Ain't he there?
- Don't he hang there?

I wouldn't call these ungrammatical, although they are in formal contexts. They are particular to a street or youth idiom. It's a reduction in the number of conjugations required, making the sentence form regular across different pronouns. It's the same form with "he", "you", "I" in the subject role.

I found it in an [AAVE feature list](http://courses.essex.ac.uk/lg/lg449/AAVEfeatureList.htm), it's 3rd singular don't on the list. But it doesn't feel specifically like AAVE, because it's not complex enough to be a unique AAVE thing, like "That ball done been lying" would be.

Answer (score -1):

> Standard English fails to distinguish between the forms of the
>   auxiliary verb *do* and its main verb forms. This is true both of
>   present tense forms, where many other dialects distinguish between
>   auxiliary *I do, he do* and main verb *I do, he does* or similar, and
>   the past tense, where most other dialects distinguish between
>   auxiliary *did* and main verb *done*, as in *You done it, did you?*

From ‘Standard English: what it isn’t’ by Peter Trudgill. Complete text [here](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/dick/SEtrudgill2011.pdf).